# How to set cells' background?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

How to set the background of several cells within a row (or of a whole row) in OpenXml?

Having read several articles:

1. [Coloring cells in excel sheet using openXML in C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/oxmlsdk/thread/a973335c-9f9b-4e70-883a-02a0bcff43d2)
2. [Advanced styling in Excel Open XML](http://polymathprogrammer.com/2009/12/21/advanced-styling-in-excel-open-xml/)

I still cannot make it work.

My task is actually at first glance seems to be somewhat easier and a little bit different from what is written in those articles. The mentioned tutorials predominantly show how to create a new document and style it. While I need to change the styling of the existing one.

That is, I have an existing *xlsx* document (a report template). I populate the report with the necessary values (managed to do it thanks to [SO open xml excel read cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115257/open-xml-excel-read-cell-value) and [MSDN Working with sheets (Open XML SDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278309.aspx)). But next I need to mark several rows with, say, red background.

I am neither sure whether to use `CellStyle` nor if I should use `CellFormat` or something else...This is what I have got up to now:

```
SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("ole.xlsx", true);

Sheet sheet = (Sheet)doc.WorkbookPart
                        .Workbook
                        .Sheets
                        .FirstOrDefault();

WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)doc.WorkbookPart
                                                .GetPartById(sheet.Id);
Worksheet worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;


CellStyle cs = new CellStyle();
cs.Name = StringValue.FromString("Normal");
cs.FormatId = 0;
cs.BuiltinId = 0;
//where are the style values?

WorkbookStylesPart wbsp = doc.WorkbookPart
                                .GetPartsOfType<WorkbookStylesPart>()
                                .FirstOrDefault();
wbsp.Stylesheet.CellStyles.Append(cs);
wbsp.Stylesheet.Save();



Cell cell = GetCell(worksheet, "A", 20);
cell.StyleIndex = 1U;//get the new cellstyle index somehow

doc.Close();
```

Actually I would greatly appreciate a more light-weight and easy example of how to style, say, cell `A20` or range from `A20` to `J20`. Or probably a link to some more consecutive tutorial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the end I changed my mind to use cell background and used fonts. Thanks to answer by *foson* in [SO Creating Excel document with OpenXml sdk 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012547/creating-excel-document-with-openxml-sdk-2-0) I managed to add a new `Font` and a new `CellFormat`, having preserved the original cell's formatting (i.e. having changed the font color only):

```
SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("1.xlsx", true);
Sheet sheet = (Sheet)doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.FirstOrDefault();
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)doc.WorkbookPart
                                                .GetPartById(sheet.Id);
Worksheet worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;

WorkbookStylesPart styles = doc.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart;
Stylesheet stylesheet = styles.Stylesheet;
CellFormats cellformats = stylesheet.CellFormats;
Fonts fonts = stylesheet.Fonts;

UInt32 fontIndex = fonts.Count;
UInt32 formatIndex = cellformats.Count;

Cell cell = GetCell(worksheet, "A", 19);
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);

CellFormat f = (CellFormat)cellformats.ElementAt((int)cell.StyleIndex.Value);

var font = (Font)fonts.ElementAt((int)f.FontId.Value);
var newfont = (Font)font.Clone();
newfont.Color = new Color() { Rgb = new HexBinaryValue("ff0000") };
fonts.Append(newfont);

CellFormat newformat = (CellFormat)f.Clone();
newformat.FontId = fontIndex;
cellformats.Append(newformat);

stylesheet.Save();

cell.StyleIndex = formatIndex;
doc.Close();
```

Comment: Question is about background of cell but the code is only talking about font color!!

Comment: For a more detailed and complete answer see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63468021/7206675)

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options:

1. Use MS lib ExcelDataReader which requires your server installing Office and usually does not work if your program is running in IIS.
2. Use closed source libs.
3. Use OpenXML.

Try my code using pure OpenXML:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59806422/6782249

Answer (score -1):

cSimple solution:
Try this: (it works with the nuget package ClosedXML v 0.95.4)

using ClosedXML.Excel;

XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();

IXLWorksheet ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Test Background Color");

ws.Cell("A1").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.LightBlue;

ws.Cell("A1").Value = "This cell should have light blue background";

wb.SaveAs(@"c:\Test\test.xlsx");

Comment: Ooops, sorry! OpenXML? Well the above is very handy...