# how to set background color of a cell in Excel via Asp.net code

Tags: asp.net

I want to set a color of my choice in some cells using Asp.Net.
Suppose,If my Salary amount is greater than 14000 than system should highlight specific cells where salary > 14000.Please Help!!

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051642/how-to-set-cells-background)

Answer (score 0):

You can color cells in excel sheet using openXML in C#

[Reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a973335c-9f9b-4e70-883a-02a0bcff43d2/coloring-cells-in-excel-sheet-using-openxml-in-c?forum=oxmlsdk)